# Unable to add a key to gpg

Tags: arch-linux, gpg

I'm trying to add a key to gpg:

```
$ gpg --recv-key 12345
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available
```

Then I do this:

```
$ gpg --list-keys
gpg: /home/me/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
```

but the error remains. How can I can fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify a keyserver to use.I typically use `--keyserver wwwkeys.uk.pgp.net` (you can use a lot of different country codes instead of `uk`, but I know that one works).

Comment: should I add it to the config instead? should there be whitespace between the 'www' and 'keys' ?

Comment: gpg: Note: '--keyserver' is not considered an option

Comment: No spaces in `wwwkeys.uk.pgp.net`. You can probably add it your configuration, and it might be a good idea, I've just never bothered to. `--keyserver` is listed in the man page, so it should work, the complete command will be something like `gpg --keyserver wwwkeys.uk.pgp.net --recv-keys 12345678`.

Comment: I think the best practice now is to put the keyserver in .gnupg/gpg.conf