# keyserver receive failed (on every keyserver available)

Tags: ubuntu, gpg, ppa

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 and I'm not able to add any ppa. 
I tried to manually add keys using different keyservers but on every attempt I'm getting keyserver received error:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0F164EEB
```

Error Received:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.qm2WNA0lTK/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0F164EEB
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No keyserver available

$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 0F164EEB
```

Error Received:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.O681PzEx7r/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 0F164EEB
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection refused
```

It is the same case with other keys. I'm not able to add any PPA.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall that might reject this protocol or that might require you to configure a proxy?

Comment: I m using a proxy but it gave the same result even when adding -E flag so  I don't think that is the issue here

Comment: `apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys XX` works for me, but it does not work without protocol part `hkp://`.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/o5rcs6/psa_you_need_to_update_your_keyserver/

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68583/is-the-pgp-web-of-trust-keyserver-infrastructure-permanently-broken

Answer (score 24):

I was getting the same 'gpg keyserver connection refused' error with gpg at the command line, GPA, and KGpg. I am using gnupg 2.1.18-8 on Debian Sid. I enabled debugging in dirmngr as follows:

```
sudo pkill dirmngr; dirmngr --debug-all --daemon --standard-resolver
```

The debugging output on the console complained about the lack of a Tor connection. It turned out that "use-tor" was enabled in `$HOME/.gnupg/dirmngr`. (Thanks, gpgconf!) I commented it out, leaving an empty `dirmngr.conf`, and keyserver communications are now working normally.

Comment: Just `sudo pkill dirmngr` solved my issue.

Comment: The additional output from this lead me to another answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1262849/730949) that fixed it for me (on Arch-based Manjaro, despite being on AskUbuntu, answer also mentions Arch).

Answer (score 10):

This also happened to me when something was wrong with the DNS resolution setup. Check that there are nameservers listed in `/etc/resolv.conf` (also, try alternative nameservers). If you are using `systemd-resolved`, then make sure that `/etc/resolv.conf` is a symlink to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 10):

For those of you stuck on this error after trying the above solutions, make sure that you've included the hkp:// protocol prefix before the keyserver address.

**This works for me:**

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0F164EEB
```

**This didn't work for me:**

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0F164EEB
```

Comment: This worked for me, just replace your key with mysql repo key from error it returns.

Answer (score 9):

This error can also be caused if you retrieve `gpg` keys through `tor` & `tor` is **not** running.

In your system log you will see:

`command 'KS_GET' failed: No keyserver available`

To retrieve keys through `tor` set in `~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf`:

```
# https://gnupg.org/blog/20151224-gnupg-in-november-and-december.html
use-tor
keyserver hkp://jirk5u4osbsr34t5.onion

# https://sks-keyservers.net/overview-of-pools.php#pool_hkps
hkp-cacert /etc/ssl/CA/sks-keyservers.netCA.pem
```

Answer (score 7):

one of the cause is indeed a proxy issue
see [Unable to add gpg key with apt-key behind a proxy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/361213/unable-to-add-gpg-key-with-apt-key-behind-a-proxy)

you would have to use the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 --keyserver-options http-proxy=http://myproxy:3128 --recv-keys 0F164EEB
```

...or a combination of curl+apt-key

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me, even though I don't use a proxy: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/664653

Answer (score 2):

For your information, I've encountered the same problem:

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection refused
```

My `resolv.conf` contained:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
search XXX.XXX
```

and was immutable:

```
$ lsattr /etc/resolv.conf
----i---------e---- /etc/resolv.conf
```

Furthermore, I didn't have a DNS server bound to the loopback network interface (127.0.0.1).

So, when I tried to execute this command

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

`apt-key` only used the first nameserver that doesn't exist and failed.

I removed the immutability:

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

I modified the first nameserver to point to a working one.

And I put the immutability back:

```
sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

And finally `apt-key` worked.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION(?): Getting same "no keyserver available" error on Parrot Security 3.6.

Used GPA v0.9.10 (Gnu Privacy Assistant).

1. Click "Server" -> "Retrieve Keys"
2. Enter , in your case 0F164EEB.
3. Click "OK". Wait a bit.

If it works, you will have an entry in the "Key Manager" listing. I was able to continue with verification process from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Step 1: Before running curl, you may want to open this directly in your browser, to check if it does exist and downloadable.  `0x0F164EEB` is the key you're looking for.
  `https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0x0F164EEB&fingerprint=on&op=get`
- Step 2: The below either command will download the specific pub-key into `target_pubkey.pgp`.

  - http-proxy: If you're behind a http-proxy such as in a company or collage network, and have difficulty accessing anything ports other than 80 or 443.
    `curl -x http://proxy:port -O target_pubkey.pgp https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0x0F164EEB&fingerprint=on&op=get`
  - socks-proxy: Or you have access to a socks-proxy, `socks5h` means the hostname is resolved remotely.
    `curl -x socks5h://proxy:port -O target_pubkey.pgp https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?search=0x0F164EEB&fingerprint=on&op=get`
- Step 3: Add the targeted key.
  `sudo apt-key add target_pubkey.pgp`
- Step 4: Add the targeted repository.
  `sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://your-targeted-repository targeted-project"`
- Step 5: Update.
  `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick and somewhat lazy solution that worked for me.

It doesn't resolve why the underlying problem is happening, it is simply a work around to get past the issue.

Basically, get the IP address of keyserver.ubuntu.com,

```
ping keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

Use CTRL-C to stop ping once the IP address is displayed.

Replace *keyserver.ubuntu.com* with it's IP address.

e.g.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
```

becomes

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver 162.213.33.8 --recv-keys 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
```

This worked for me on an older distro where I didn't want to figure out the DNS issue, I just wanted to install the key.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

before you run

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 0F164EEB
```

And if you have an "echo" line before that, run *another* `sudo apt-get update` even before that:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN sh -c 'echo "..." > /etc/...'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-key adv ...
```

By this, I got rid of the similar error "Cannot assign requested address":

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.Up2U8vHXpt/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Cannot assign requested address
ERROR: Service 'listener' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

#### UPDATE

**Most likely: server is just busy, try again**

The whole idea abobe is likely just a placebo since [this answer to the same error, but in another context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7654521/11154841) says that this can appear **when the address is just busy**. Which would mean: if you have this error, just try again, and `sudo apt-get update` might not change anything, then. That sounds most likely.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use `keyserver.ubuntu.com` from GnuPG only after adding a `hkps://` prefix and a `:443` suffix:

```
gpg2 --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 --recv-keys XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Replace `gpg2` with `apt-key adv` in case you need to fetch a key for APT. In my case, I needed to import it into my user keyring for another purpose.

Thanks to [Cyril Chaboisseau](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/136387)'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516780) for providing a hint.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:

1. change DNS to primary 8.8.8.8, secondary DNS 192.168.1.1 (local router)
2. use gpg instead of apt-key which is now depreciated
3. add protocol "hkp://" and port 80 to key server address
4. reboot

cli command:

```
    sudo gpg  --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 1C61A2656FB57B7E4DE0F4C1FC918B335044912E 
[sudo] password for rd: 
gpg: /root/.gnupg/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key FC918B335044912E: public key "Dropbox Automatic Signing Key <linux@dropbox.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1e
```

Answer (score 0):

Others have gone over many reasons for seeing this error message. I just ran across another:

---

If your host only has IPv6 access, some keyservers are IPv4 only!

Currently Ubuntu has a longstanding bug on this issue:
https://answers.launchpad.net/launchpad/+question/189094

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 22.04 (and possibly in 20.04 and 18.04) just convert the key to lower case, prefix it with a `0x`, fetch it via https from the intended keyserver and copy it to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/` with the extension `.asc` - obsoletes all apt-key or gpg torture.

E.g. one may use this little ksh script as a workaround:

```bash
#!/bin/ksh93

typeset -l KEY
typeset -u UC
typeset K F
integer N=0

if [[ -z "$1" ]]; then
    print -u2 "Usage: ${0##*/} key ..."
    exit 1
fi
TMP=${ mktemp -d -p /tmp pkgkey.XXXXXX ; }
[[ -z ${TMP} ]] && exit 99

for K ; do
    KEY="$K"
    [[ ${KEY:0:2} == '0x' ]] && KEY="${KEY:2}"
    if [[ ! ${KEY} =~ ^[0-9a-f]+$ ]]; then
        print -u2 "Ignoring invalid key '$K'."
        continue
    fi
    UC=${KEY}
    F="${TMP}/${UC}.asc"
    wget -O "$F" \
        "https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&search=0x${KEY}"
    grep -qs -- '-BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-' "$F" && (( N++ > -1 )) || rm -f "$F"
done
(( N )) && sudo cp "${TMP}/"*.asc /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
rm -rf "${TMP}"
```

If stored as apt-key.sh and `chmod 0755 apt-key.sh` one may e.g. `apt-key.sh DDCAE044F796ECB0` ;-).